# html5 audio element return src with jquery

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am converting some HTML5 to work with Android.  Android does not support the  element, so the play method does not function.

I am using PhoneGap's media element, and that does play audio.  What I want, is a way to find the first source of the audio tag, and then use that with media play, but this does not seem to work.

```
function playSound(whatToPlay) {
    // removed since <audio does not work
    // var snd = document.getElementById(whatToPlay);
    // snd.play();

    toPlaySrc = $("#"+whatToPlay+":first-child").eq(0).attr("src");
    // next I will have to deal with /android_asset and my current partial path
    myMedia = new Media("/android_asset/"+toPlaySrc, onSuccess,onError);
    if (myMedia)
        myMedia.play();        
}
playSound("clockticking");
```

this is my audio element.

```
<audio id="clockticking" preload="auto" autobuffer onEnded="instructionFinsihed()">
  <source src="../sound/tictoc.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
  <source src="../sound/tictoc.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

I have many existing audio elements, so a general solution would really be important, I can not, for instance just ad id tags to all the mp3 elements and solve it.

Comment: I'm working on a small lib that you can add to Cordova/PhoneGap Android to monkey patch issues like this. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm sure I cant be the only one with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm working on some monkey patch code for the Android WebView, you can see the progress over on my [corinthian github project](https://github.com/macdonst/corinthian/). In the meantime what you'd want to do is setup a on deviceready listener:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", monkeypunch, true);
```

create an array to hold the media objects:

```
mediaObjs = [];
```

and in the monkeypunch method you would do:

```
function monkeypunch() {
    var audioclips = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
    for (var i=0; i < audioclips.length; i++) {
        // Create new Media object.
        var audioSrc = audioclips[i].firstElementChild.src;
        if (audioSrc.indexOf("file:///android_asset") == 0) {
            audioSrc = audioSrc.substring(7);
        }
        mediaObjs[audioSrc] = new Media(audioSrc);
        // Create the HTML
        var newAudio = document.createElement('div');
        var newImg = document.createElement('img');
        newImg.setAttribute('src', 'images/play.png');
        newAudio.appendChild(newImg);
        // Set the onclick listener
        newAudio.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // figure out what image is displayed
            if (newImg.src.indexOf("images/play.png", newImg.src.length - "images/play.png".length) !== -1) {
                newImg.src = "images/pause.png"; 
                mediaObjs[audioSrc].play();               
            } else {
                newImg.src = "images/play.png";
                mediaObjs[audioSrc].pause();                
            }
        });
        // replace the audio tag with out div
        audioclips[i].parentNode.replaceChild(newAudio, audioclips[i]);
    }
}
```

You can grab the play/pause images from my github project. I'm planning on adding more functionality when I have some more time.